# ¿Como se llama el comando opuesto al comando (source) de bash de git?

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

Amigos me gustaria saber cual es el comando opuesto al comando source, este comando en la terminal permite abrir literalmente cualquier programa. ejemplo; source ["programa" como vs code] ["argumento" como index.html], pero principalmente este comando abre archivos relacionados con el shell de bash es decir archivos .bash, .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.
y me gustaria saber cual seria ese comando opuesto para cerrar esa instancia de cualquiera de  esos archivos, (ver imagen) abro el .bashrc con el comando source y ahora quiero cerrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la pregunta no tiene mucho sentido.... o en todo caso la respuesta sería **"no existe tal cosa"**.

`source` no hace nada mágico. Si tu llamas a un script x *sin source*, el intérprete invoca una **nueva instancia** del intérprete que corresponda para tal archivo (que no necesariamente es bash).

Cuando el script termina de ejecutarse, dicha instancia muere y regresas a la instancia de terminal original desde la que hiciste la ejecución.

Lo que hace `source` es pedirle *al intérprete actual* que ejecute lo que está en el script (sin arrancar una instancia nueva). Por eso es que cosas como asignación de variables en scripts hay que ejecutarlos con `source`, porque si no, dicha inicialización se hace en otra instancia del intérprete que se cierra al terminar el script y el intérprete original no ve dichas asignaciones.

Habiendo dicho esto, pues no hay forma de cerrar eso que arrancaste con un `source`, a menos que dichas cosas que arrancas presenten mecanismos para ello... por ejemplo, en tu script arrancas postgres.... pues podrías detener postgres, pero no es mágicamente a través de un comando especial que mirará el script para saber qué hay que hacer para ejecutar lo contrario de dicho script.

Comment: Entiendo amigo gracias, pensaba que las lineas de codigo del archivo .bash_profile podian ser "eliminadas" no estar en memoria, no se existe ese comando magico XD, pero mira se me ocurrio hacer un comando que cambie y remplace los comandos que no quiero que se ejecuten, es decir, seria ejecutar .basrc normal y al escribir un comando que se crea con alias vuelba a ejecutar el mismo .bashrc y con los cambios que quiera

Comment: @ManuelCaro Puedes lanzar un nuevo shell tras hacer cambios en `.bashrc`, simplemente invocando el comando `bash`. Creo que eso haría lo que pides.

Comment: Bingo amigo gracias, pues es imposible dejar de ejecutar un .bashrc cuando ya fue ejecutado con source ~/bashrc, tocaria solo ejecutar el comando bash para que genere el en la misma terminal el mismo shell

Comment: Aunque esa era mi duda si existia un comando para cerrar ese .bashrc especifico mas no todo el shell, pero sirve

Comment: No entiendo que es cerrar ese ".bashrc" específico. Algo que podrías hacer es hacer todo a mano. Es decir, leer que hace **ese .bashrc** y, solo con base en eso, deshacer lo que hace. Por ejemplo, si exporta algo, entonces eliminas la variable; si abre un programa, entonces buscas que lo cierre. Pero todo lo tendrías que hacer tú con tus manos de programador.

Answer (score 1):

### Crear un script llamado `unsource`

Si bien no existe comando opuesto a `source`, puedes crear uno y tengo una idea de cómo hacerlo.

Algo que suele ir en los archivos de configuración (que terminan con `rc`) son cosas como:

1. Modificar la variable PATH
2. exportar variables de entorno
3. Crear alias de comandos
4. Iniciar programas
5. Otras cosas

Entonces, sabiendo estas cosas, porías crear un script con expresiones regulares que busque lo que hay dentro de ese archivo, y, siguiendo nuestra suposición de lo que hace el archivo de configuración:

1. Reinicializar la variable PATH a su configuración inicial al declararla como suele estar en `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. O puedes buscar las ocurrencias de la variable PATH, los directorios que le fueron añadidos y que están separados por los dos puntos, y luego, a tu variable PATH de tu ambiente principal, quitarle cada una de esas ocurrencias.
2. Buscar el patrón de cada variable con una expresión regular como `export (.+)=.*` y, al obtener esa variable, aplicarle un `unset`
3. Hacer lo mismo pero para los alias. Es decir, buscar algo con `^alias (.+)=.*`, y a lo que capture aplicarle un `unalias`
4. Tratar de aplicar una heurística para encontrar los comandos ejecutados. Quizás algo como encontrar las primeras palabras que no empiecen con `export`, `alias`, pound signs ("#"), y listarlos en los procesos con `pgrep`, obtener si `id` de ejecución y enviarles la señal de `SIGTERM` o `SIGKILL` con el comando `kill`
5. Ver qué otras cosas hace y aplicarles la inversa a lo que hace.

Una vez que tengas el script que hace eso, le tienes que aplicar un `source` a ese script.

Y si logras crear un script tan flexible y sólido. Crea un repo y llámale `unsource`, y luego ofrecelo a la comunidad de GNU/Linux.

### Crear un nuevo ambiente

Puedes salirte de tu terminal o loggearte en otra, por ejemplo, en una que use una versión nueva de zsh, fish. O relogearte con un usuario que creaste y que no tiene ningún configuración mayor.

Por ejemplo, crea un usuario con:

```
$ adduser usuario_inocente
```

Y luego loggeate con:

```
$ su usuario_inocente
```

Y listo.

El problema serán los permisos de ese usuario sobre archivos o programas que quieras correr o abrir.

Otra es que guardes un respaldo de tu archivo `.bashrc` con:

```
$ mv ~/.bashrc{,.bak}
```

Y con esto habras cambiado de nombre tu archivo y por lo tanto no será utilizado por bash.

Luego de esto tendrás que reiniciar tu equipo para asegurarte que todos los programas y subprocesos fueron cerrados (es esto o buscar todo con `pgrep`, `pkill`, y `xargs`. Es decir, depende de lo que haya en tu archivo `.bashrc`).